# Problem with Extend Line tool in ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.1

I have a problem with [Extend Line tool in ArcPy](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001v00000004000000), it cannot extend some lines, i tried to get around by erasing the edges of lines that i want to extend without failure, but despite this some fewer lines remains not extended to any feature in the same layer.

an example of Extend commande

```
arcpy.ExtendLine_edit("Line_fc" , "", "FEATURE")
```

Comment: Have you checked the last 2 nodes of the lines that are not extending?  Sometimes it will have a "jog" or "angle" that will cause the features to not extend in the direction or within the distance you have specified.  You could also try expanding your "Extend" distance to see if they extend in a "wrong direction".

Comment: i don't put max distance parameter, so the line will be stopped by the nearest feature. i tried deleting those "jogs" by erasing the edges of the line by a buffer on line vertex points

Comment: Can you post some shp samples, or at least a screenshot? of your data?

Comment: i have discovered that the line that couldn't be extended was overlapped with a identical feature, then i deleted dupllicates using "DeleteIdentical_management".

Comment: since you answered your own question, please post your last comment as the "Answer" and go ahead and accept it.  Glad you found the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have discovered that the line that couldn't be extended was overlapped with a identical feature, then i deleted duplicates using `DeleteIdentical_management`